# Iterate over nested lists in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to figure out this problem quite a while and only solutions I have found are really ugly. There must be a much nicer way to solve this:

Given the configuration

```
iterations = 2
tasklist = [
  {:system, print: "sth"},
  {:system, loop: [
    {:device1, run: "cmd" },
    {:device2, run: "cmd" },
  ], iterations: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" },
]
```

Configuration is being processed from top to the bottom and every command will print some result (output to CSV file), except `{:system, loop: []}`. Command definitions are different and can include ranges as an input value.

I would like to create a function which allows me to implement nested loops by expanding this configuration to the new list of steps without loop and iterations but with keeping this information inside every step. So the software is able to extract total iteration count and current iteration number from step if the step's input value is range and use it to do some other calculations.

So basically a function which transforms the original configuration to this:

```
tasklist = [
  {:system, print: "sth",mainiteration: 1, maintotalit: 2},
  {:device1, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 1, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device2, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 1, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" ,mainiteration: 1, maintotalit: 2},

  {:system, print: "sth",mainiteration: 1, maintotalit: 2},
  {:device1, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 2, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device2, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 2, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" ,mainiteration: 1, maintotalit: 2},

  {:system, print: "sth",mainiteration: 1, maintotalit: 2},
  {:device1, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 3, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device2, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 3, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" ,mainiteration: 1, maintotalit: 2},

  {:system, print: "sth",mainiteration: 2, maintotalit: 2},
  {:device1, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 1, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device2, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 1, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" ,mainiteration: 2, maintotalit: 2},

  {:system, print: "sth",mainiteration: 2, maintotalit: 2},
  {:device1, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 2, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device2, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 2, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" ,mainiteration: 2, maintotalit: 2},

  {:system, print: "sth",mainiteration: 2, maintotalit: 2},
  {:device1, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 3, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device2, run: "cmd" ,loopiteration: 3, looptotalit: 3},
  {:device3, run: "cmd" ,mainiteration: 2, maintotalit: 2},
]
```

---

Current code which goes through the configuration steps is:

```
Enum.each(1..iterations, fn n ->  
  Enum.each(tasklist, fn task ->
     IO.inspect(task) # My custom implementation
  end)
end)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. For starters, there are no "loops" in Elixir. Please post your actual code. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Actually, there are a lot of ways how to do loops but I understand your point, the subject is not so accurate but I don't have an idea how to describe it better :) Also I have updated my question to include current code running those steps described in tasklist variable. But this is nothing special and I thought the better solution would be to expand tasklist before processing and leave processing the same.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish. But my answer still holds. If you want to transform the original list, use `reduce` instead of `each`.

Comment: Also shouldn't your transformed list [look like this](https://pastebin.com/KVZsmDw3)? (ignoring the extra params for now)

Comment: @Sheharyar No, because this will break the result table. Each iteration of the whole tasklist is a new line of CSV and each task inside is one value for CSV. SO when I want to expand nested lists I also have to run commands outside loop to get a consistent number of values per line

and yes, the code example is for processing lines, not for the transformation, I am trying to implement reduce but I think your answer is even better than to use Enum.reduce

Answer (score 2):

*Welcome to Stack Overflow!*

For starters, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is an immutable, functional language so the common [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) based concept of "loops" that you might be familiar with, doesn't really apply here. But of course you can still iterate over collections of data in other ways, including [`each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2), [`map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2), [`reduce/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) and  [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html).

If you simply want to print the result of each item or fire an one-off event in the iteration and not return anything, `each/2` is the simplest option, otherwise you're better off with `map/2` or `reduce/3`

---

Getting to your actual question, you can achieve that by **handling each scenario of your task list in a module using pattern matching in function clauses and recursion:**

```ex
defmodule TaskList do
  def handle({:system, print: message}) do
    IO.puts(message)
  end

  def handle({:system, loop: tasks, iterations: count}) do
    Enum.each(1..count, fn _ ->
      Enum.each(tasks, &handle/1)
    end)
  end

  def handle({device, run: command}) do
    # Call your command on the device
    # (Replace with your own implementation)
  end

  def handle(unknown) do
    # Do nothing or handle unexpected situations here
  end

  def process_all(tasks, iterations) when is_list(tasks) do
    handle({:system, loop: tasks, iterations: iterations})
  end
end
```

After making a few minor changes depending on how you want your output, you can then call it like this:

```ex
TaskList.process_all(my_tasks, 2)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. This looks very nice compared to my functions for processing tasks and I will implement it later. But I think, my original answer is slightly different and if I look back, much more simple than my current explanation above... So, sorry for a bad explanation from my side, I have updated question to be more specific.

Comment: loops are not an oop concept, please be so kind, as to consider removing this irrelevant and wrong introduction to your answer.

Comment: @TomRegner I know, but most FP beginners have a very one-sided mutation-based view of loops, which can hinder their understanding. That's why I wrote "the classical oop-based concept of loops". Though i could certainly improve the wording.

Comment: Maybe 'loop concept of imperative languages' -- lisp predates most non-fp languages in use these days :)

Comment: @Sheharyar I think your solution is pretty neat, it should be also used to transform my task list as I need... trying to update your code and post a result here

Comment: Ok, I have slightly updated your code and the only thing that I can't solve is how to pass more arguments to the handle call inside Enum.each. Instead of &handle/1

`def handle({:system, loop: tasks, iterations: count}) do
    Enum.each(1..count, fn num ->
      Enum.each(tasks, &handle/1) #need to pass task,totaliterations and currentiteration
    end)
  end
`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the original problem was too complex to solve it this way... We decided to not integrate nested lists option like it was described and instead integrate just one initialization section on the top of the rest of software. So the final code looks like that, just for the record:

```
initit = 3
initlist = 
  [
    {:system, print: 10..15, header: "\tInitHeader1"},
  ]

mainit = 2
tasklist =
  [
    {:system, print: 1..5, header: "\tMainTaskHeader1"},
    {:system, print: 2..10, header: "\tMainTaskHeader2"}
  ]

Enum.each(1..initit, fn i ->
    Enum.each(1..mainit, fn t ->

      Enum.each(initlist, fn task ->
        runTask(task, initit, i)
      end)

      Enum.each(tasklist, fn task ->
        runTask(task, mainit, t)
      end)

    end)
  end)
```

Thanks very much to all.